# How to upload Assets to FirebaseStorage in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, file, dart, firebase-storage, assets

Here is my challenge:

I'm using the following method to select multiple images from my phone gallery (package `multi_image_picker:`needs to be added in pubspec.yaml)

```dart
    Future<void> loadAssets() async {
        List<Asset> resultList = <Asset>[];
        String error = 'No Error Detected';
    
        try {
          resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
            maxImages: 300,
            enableCamera: true,
            selectedAssets: images,
            cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
            materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
              actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
              actionBarTitle: "Example App",
              allViewTitle: "All Photos",
              useDetailsView: false,
              selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
            ),
          );
          for (int i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
            print('resultList[i].name: ${resultList[i].name}');
          }
        } on Exception catch (e) {
          error = e.toString();
        }
    
        if (!mounted) return;
    
        setState(() {
          images = resultList;
          _error = error;
        });
      }
```

My variable `resultList`stores instances of Assets. I would like to upload those assets to a certain path in my FirebaseStorage.

In the past, I was using the package `image_picker:` which allowed me to select only one image from my phone gallery. But the `image_picker` could store the selected images as Type of File instead of Assets and from the Type of File I'm able to get the image-path which I could use to upload the image to my FirebaseStorage.

But I have no clue how to upload the Assets getting from the method `loadhAssets()` to my FirebaseStorage.
Anyone has an idea how to solve that?

I hope my concern was clear enough.
Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#example) package also allows you to pick multiple images, not just one. I have a sample implementation code here:

```
  List<XFile> selectedImages = [];
  
  Future<void> pickImages() async {
    final pickedFileList = await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage();
    if (pickedFileList != null) {
      setState(() {
          selectedImages = pickedFileList;
      });
    }
  }
```

And here's how you can upload your selected images to Firebase Storage:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
Reference storageRef = storage.ref();
List<String> imgURL = []; //to store url of uploaded images

  Future<void> uploadSelectedImages() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedImages.length; i++) {
      final ref = storageRef.child('Photos/image$i');
      await ref.putFile(File(selectedImages[i].path)).whenComplete(() async {
        await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) { //upload and get URL
          setState(() {
            imgURL.add(value);
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Hope this help!